# Get vertex value that shapes 90 degrees with triangle centroid

Tags: math, height, vertex, centroid

I have this triangle:

[image]

I'm trying to get the vertex value highlighted in the green circle in order to draw that red line. Is there any equation that I can use to extract that value?

```
The centroid vertex G = (x=5.5, y=1.5)
The other vertex B = (x=0, y=1)
and the last vertex C = (x=7, y=0)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I know it might be a 5th grade math but I can't think of a way to calculate this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw away the majority of the triangle and just keep the vector B->G and the vector B->C then this problem shows itself to be a "vector projection" problem. 
These are solved analytically using the dot product of the 2 vectors and are well documented elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Took me 2 days to figure this out, you basically need to get the slopes for the base vector and the altitude vector (centroid), then solve this equation: `y = m * x + b` for both vectors (the base + altitude). Then you'll get 2 different equations that you need to use substitution to get the x first then apply that value to the 2nd equation to get the y. For more information watch this youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuEbWkF5lcM

Here's the solution in PHP (pseudo) if anyone is interested:

```
    //slope of base
    $m1 = getSlope(baseVector);

    //slope of altitude (invert and divide it by 1)
    $m2 = 1/-$m1;

    //points
    $x1 = $baseVector->x;
    $y1 = $baseVector->y;

    //Centroid vertex
    $x2 = $center['x'];
    $y2 = $center['y'];

    //altitude equation: y = m * x + b
    //eq1: y1 = (m1 * x1) + b1 then find b1
    $b1 = -($m1 * $x1) + $y1;
    //equation: y = ($m1 * x) + $b1

    //eq2: y2 = (m2 * x2) + b2 then find b2
    $b2 = -($m2 * $x2) + $y2;
    //equation: y = ($m2 * x) + $b2;

    //substitute eq1 into eq2 and find x
    //merge the equations (move the Xs to the left side and numbers on the right side)
    $Xs = $m1 - $m2; //left side (number of Xs)
    $Bs = $b2 - $b1; //right side
    $x = $Bs / $Xs; //get x number
    $y = ($m2 * $x) + $b2; //get y number
```